# How do I uninstall RHEL7?

Tags: rhel, uninstall

I am trying to replace my operating system. How do I uninstall RHEL7? How do I install a new operating system (non Linux)?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are not concerned about data, that might be possible to recover, you need not uninstall or delete/shred anything. You simply install the new operating system and let it use the whole drive.

Comment: Installing a new Operating System is a broad question, and only on-topic for certain OS's here at U&L.

Answer (score 2):

There will be two things involved:

1. Erase the disk and start installing the new OS, or erase it during the installation, or don't erase it if you don't need to or don't want to.
2. Unregister RHEL from your BIOS safe bootup if applicable.

Before you begin, note that you might prefer to perform step 2. before you erase your RHEL.

Comment: You also might want to terminate your subscription, if any, to services for which you might be paying Red Hat.